# How does one type this default value in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, generics, default-value, return-type, typing

Sorry for the vague title, but I don't know how to express this problem concisely.

Basically, I have the following code (with unimportant bits removed):

```
function identity<T>(value: T): T {
    return value;
}

function extent<T, K>(
    values: T[],
    map: (value: T) => K = identity // the '= identity' part gives an error
): [K, K] | undefined {
    let min;
    let max;

    // ... stuff ...

    return min === undefined || max === undefined ? undefined : [map(min), map(max)];
}
```

Where the default `= identity` value results in a compiler error.

I can remove the default value for the `map` parameter from the `extent`'s signature and always provide one myself:

```
extent([5, 1, 3, 4, 8], x => x)
```

Which will work just fine, but I'd rather not supply the second parameter, unless I'm actually mapping the values from one type to another.

How do I type the `indentity` function so that it's accepted as the default value for `extent`'s `map` parameter? I'm stuck on TypeScript 3.6 for the time being, if that matteres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best way to deal with this that maintains type-safety to the outside world is via overloads:

```
function extent<T>(values: T[]): [T, T] | undefined
function extent<T, K>(values: T[], map: (value: T) => K): [K, K] | undefined
function extent<T, K>(
  values: T[],
  map?: (value: T) => K 
): [K, K] | [T, T] | undefined {
  const actualMap = map ?? identity;
  let min;
  let max;

  // ... stuff ...

  return min === undefined || 
         max === undefined ? 
             undefined : 
             [actualMap(min), actualMap(max)];
}
```

Comment: Awesome! That’s the no compromise solution I’ve been looking for! Thanks 

Comment: Actually, it still fails if I declare the type of min/max: `let min: T; let max: T;` I mean, in my code I don't have to declare it because it is inferred by the compiler from the code section I omitted (marked as "... stuff ..."), but it fails nontheless. So the return type of extent should be not `[K, K] | [T, T] | undefined` but `[T | K, T | K] | undefined`, but this solution is still valid 

Comment: @Vitaly I had the same `identity` function with the same signature in some of my own projects, and it took a short while to get this clean (or at least, clean for any consumers!). Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of type error.

In `map` parameter you declare that this function will return the type of `K` but in the `identity` function you expect that to return the type of `T` so you can't assign it as a default value.

You could fix it like this: `map: (value: K) => K = identity`

Comment: That's not going to be much use if the mapping is to something other than `K`.

Comment: Yeah, I just quickly answer in the author's case.

Answer (score 0):

There is a conflict with `T => K` type of map and `K => K` type in identity function. Making `identity` less strict on types can help:

```
function identity<T>(value: T): any {
    return value;
}
```

or even

```
const identity = (x: any) => x;
```

Comment: Yes, but then the compiler won’t be able to properly infer the return type of the `extent` function. It would be either `[unknown, unknown]` or `[any, any]`.